# How to Read Javascript Config Pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jwplayer

If I want to create function to alert title name in this code, how to write function to alert it without including jwplayer library to my HTML file?

[**http://jsfiddle.net/fs7p0ec4/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/fs7p0ec4/1/)

```js
jwplayer( "my_media_player" ).setup({
 image: "http://example.com/poster.jpg",
 title: "testHLS",
 rtmp: { bufferlength: "2" },
 bufferlength: "2",
 width: "100%",
 aspectratio : "16:9",
 playlist: [{sources: [ { file: "http://example.com/playlist.m3u8" } ]}],
primary: "flash",
repeat: true,
controlbar: true,
stretching: "exactfit"
});
```

Comment: To clarify, you don't want `jwplayer.js` to be in your actual webpage? Meaning you don't want to put 
 `<script src="https://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="{{{{{{{KEY}}}}}}}}}}";</script>`
   on the page?

Comment: yes, I dont want to  put jwplayer.js on page

Comment: The only way I know is by using JW Platform. Look for **Option 1** in this [ARTICLE](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1406723-basic-video-embed)

Comment: problem solved `var jwplayerClass = function(xx){
}

jwplayerClass.prototype.setup = function(info) {
    
    var XWP = info.playlist[0].sources[0].file;
alert(XWP);
return this 
     };

var jwplayer = function (xx) {
  return new jwplayerClass(xx);
};`

Comment: Great! :) Post as an answer. Any unraveled mystery of JW Player should be documented ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jwplayerClass = function(xx){ }
jwplayerClass.prototype.setup = function(info) {
   var XWP = info.playlist[0].sources[0].file; 
   alert(XWP); return this 
};
var jwplayer = function (xx) { 
    return new jwplayerClass(xx); 
};
```